# Maven ignores scm tag

Tags: java, git, maven, version-control

I'm trying to execute `mvn release:prepare` command, but I get the message **scm connection or developerconnection must be specified**.

I do have `<scm>` section in the `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

   <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>7</version>
    </parent>

    ...

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/repository-name</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/repository-name</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/repository-name</url>
    </scm>
</project>
```

Maven version is 3.2.3. What's wrong?

Comment: That looks clone enough to http://www.baeldung.com/maven-release-nexus. Any chance the url might be incorrect? Maybe you can try setting the url with the same connection value? (as in https://github.com/ioos/ioos-sos-common/blob/master/pom.xml#L40)

Comment: @VonC, you are right. I just had to add `.git` at the end of each item of the `<scm>`. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect. I have added an answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [OP Anton Golovin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802875/anton-golovin)'s [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289493/maven-ignores-scm-tag/26295897#comment41261133_26289493), adding `.git` at the end of `<scm>` items was enough:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/repository-name.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/repository-name.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/repository-name.git</url>
</scm>
```